# How to change a formula according to cell value in excel?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have a list of all my expenditures in Excel. Each day takes a line.

What do I want is to compare the difference between 2 days according to values on another cell. Example of formula. = A250 - A191 . I want to change this 250 and 191 just writing 321 and 192 in any anothe cell, automatically changing the formula to: = A321-A192.

Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**First approach** (better one):

Use [INDEX](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/index-function-HP010342608.aspx) function:

```
=INDEX(A:A,Z1,1)-INDEX(A:A,Z2,1)
```

where `Z1` contains `321` and `Z2` contains `192`

**Second approach** (maybe sligtly simplier to understand, but I don't recomend you to use it, since [INDIRECT](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/indirect-HP005209139.aspx) is [volatile function](http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsi.htm) and it recalculates each time *any* cell changed):

```
=INDIRECT("A" & Z1) - INDIRECT("A" & Z2)
```